# How to resolve the Cannot await in the filter expression?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-6.0

I am following the code example from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code

```
try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) when (!TodoItemExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
```

Where as in my code, the method TodoItemExists (in my case the method name is UserExists) is async.

Code sample:

```cs
try
{
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) when (!await UserExists(id))
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

Error: Cannot await in the filter expression

What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1199

Comment: You'll have to apply the condition within the catch block like you normally would prior in older versions.

Comment: Why is there negative votes to this genuine question

Comment: Not the down-voter, but you probably have a bigger problem - the **error handler** for a _database failure_ that has an **immediate dependency** on the database for its **decision processing** is _problematic_.   What happens if the database is down?

Comment: @MickyD - I am exploring the tutorial given by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code

Comment: @MickyD - what is the way to handle the database down situation?

Comment: @MickeyD would a concurrency exception really arise from a down database?

Comment: @CaiusJard you missed the essence I’m afraid

Comment: Do explain then..

Comment: I'm surprised by the negative marks for genuine question.

Comment: @CaiusJard you do realise that `TodoItemExists` (_"in my case the method name is `UserExists`"_) is making a database call?  The original MS code is a poor example of `when` and a naïve approach to error handling

Comment: Sure, but if the DbConcurrencyException has literally just come from the DB a few milliseconds ago, the database is probably up.. ?

Comment: Waht exactly does DbConcurrencyException mean? 2 people tried to update same record? Or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "old" way:

```
try
{
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) 
{
    if (!await UserExists(id)) 
      return NotFound();
    else   
      throw;
}
```

But you might want to return something else in the case of "the user was found but someone else modified it first" so the client can decide what to do - maybe even send the current state. Seems to me the client/user is reasonably the only thing that can resolve a "skip/overwrite/merge" choice